# Randomly sample same location in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Consider two dataframes `df1` and `df2` each having N columns and M rows.

I want to randomly sample the same location in both the dataframes.

To sample one location in `df1`, I use

```
df1.sample(1,axis=1).sample(1,axis=0)
```

I want to sample the same location in the other dataframe. This sampling would happen `k` times (think of it as producing k tuples where each tuple is the data from a particular column and particular row) and each time, I need a new and unique location.

I tried the following:

```
for i in xrange(k):

    a = df1.sample(1, axis=1).sample(1, axis=0)

    b = df2[a.index]
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2679, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2723, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1327, in _convert_to_indexer
    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
KeyError: "Int64Index([5], dtype='int64') not in index"
```

Should I be resorting to `Numpy` to generate unique location values and then index into those locations? Or is there a way to achieve this within pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with `numpy.random.choice` with position select `.iloc`

```
idx=np.random.choice(df1.shape[0], replace=False, size=1)
idc=np.random.choice(df1.shape[1], replace=False, size=1)

df2.iloc[idx,idc]#df1.iloc[idx,idc]
```

Answer (score 0):

A crude way of doing it:

```
first_sample = df1.sample(1, axis=1).sample(1, axis=0)

second_sample = df2.iloc[first_sample.index.tolist()][first_sample.columns.tolist()]
```